# extract snapshot of git repository at a given time

Tags: git

I have cloned a xorg git repository:

```
git clone git://anonscm.debian.org/pkg-xorg/driver/xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

and I need to extract all files as they looked after commit 45c09bfe58c37bbf7965af25bdd4fa5c37c0908f

I know how to extract one file of a specified version, i.e.

```
git show 45c09bfe58c37bbf7965af25bdd4fa5c37c0908f:src/intel_driver.h > intel_driver.h
```

but how can I extract the whole structure (all files) ?

Comment: `git checkout`? `git archive`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To check out a specific commit:

```
git checkout 45c09bfe58c37bbf7965af25bdd4fa5c37c0908f
```

This will report an error if it would need to overwrite files that are not committed. To unconditionally overwrite file, pass the `-f` option.

To extract a commit without affecting the working copy:

```
git archive 45c09bfe58c37bbf7965af25bdd4fa5c37c0908f | gzip >../45c09bfe58c37bbf7965af25bdd4fa5c37c0908f.tar.gz
git archive --prefix=45c09bfe58c37bbf7965af25bdd4fa5c37c0908f/ 45c09bfe58c37bbf7965af25bdd4fa5c37c0908f | tar xf - -C ..
```

`git archive` gives you a tar archive, which you can extract elsewhere or store to a file.